# How to view pdf file inside the public/ folder on browser in laravel

Tags: pdf, laravel, laravel-4, http-headers

I have pdf files inside my `public/` folder lets say

> public/uploads/overviews/myfile.pdf

when i try to access it on my browser like

> `http://localhost:8000/uploads/overviews/myfile.pdf`

it is being downloaded instead to be loaded on browser.

How can I load the pdf file on the browser without getting downloaded by the user?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following PHP code for view the PDF files:

```
<a href="view.php">View File</a>
```

And the `view.php` page has the following code:

```
<?php

$path="uploads/overviews/myfile.pdf";

header('content-type:application/pdf');

echo file_get_contents($path);

?>
```

Comment: tnx thats working. How can I achieve it using laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line before your link -

Example -

```
     <object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="98%" height="80%">

     <a  href="http://localhost:8000/uploads/overviews/myfile.pdf">...view Myfile..</a>
```

Comment: no good. its overlapping with the link. and the file is still being downloaded

Comment: overlapping ? means what is exactly u r seeing ? can u provide link of that page ?

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code :

```
return Response::make(file_get_contents('uploads/overviews/myfile.pdf'), 200, [
                'content-type'=>'application/pdf',
            ]);
```

Comment: Please elaborate, it is even hard to figure out if this answers the question